# Building matrix so that the inner product of columns results in an element of another matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

Let
$$A_{n \times n} = \begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}\quad a_{12}\quad ... \quad a_{1n}\\
a_{21}\quad a_{22}\quad ... \quad a_{2n}\\
.\\.\\.\\
a_{n1}\quad a_{n2}\quad ... \quad a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}$$ be symmetric and assume that $\operatorname{rank}(A)\neq 1$, for any purpose.

I need to find
$$W_{m \times n} = \begin{bmatrix}w_1\quad w_2\quad ...\quad w_n\end{bmatrix}$$
so that
$$<w_i,w_j>\,\approx\,a_{ij}\qquad \forall i,j$$

> Is there an algorithm for that?

Comment: Take an eigendecomposition $A=UDU^T$ where $U$ is orthogonal and $D$ is diagonal and set $W=UD^{1/2}$. There are many methods for that. Note that this is also the SVD of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

As $A$ is symmetric there exists (see [eigendecomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Real_symmetric_matrices)) an orthogonal matrix $U\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$, i.e. $UU^\top = I$, and a diagonal matrix $D=\operatorname{diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_n)\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$ such that $A = UDU^\top$. Now, let $D^{1/2}=\operatorname{diag}(d_1^{1/2},\ldots,d_n^{1/2})$ and set $W=D^{1/2}U^\top$. We obtain
$$\langle w_i,w_j\rangle = (W^\top W)_{i,j} = \Big((D^{1/2}U^T)^\top D^{1/2}U^\top\Big)_{i,j}= (UD^{1/2}D^{1/2}U^\top)_{i,j} = A_{i,j}\qquad \forall i,j.$$
There are many numerical method for computing the eigendecomposition of a symmetric matrix. In particular, you can use any [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular-value_decomposition) solver to find $U$ and $D^2$.

Note if $A$ is also [positive semi-definite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix), i.e. all its eigenvalues are nonnegative, then you may also perform a [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition).

Comment: But doing so, $W\in\Bbb R^{n\times n}$. I needed  $W\in\Bbb R^{m\times n}$ with $m\neq n$

Comment: @GabrielMilan ok.. I did not see that in your post. Then, you can trunkate the smallest eigenvalues

Comment: But wouldn't it be problematic? $$W\in\Bbb R^{m\times n}\,=\,U_{n\times n}D_{m\times n}\,^{1/2}$$
The dimensions don't match.
Would it be the same if I considered $W = D^{1/2}U^T$?

Comment: @GabrielMilan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-rank_approximation#Basic_low-rank_approximation_problem